# Automatically label groupplots (A), (B), (C),

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Is there a way to automatically label a set of `groupplots` from the `pgfplots` package (A), (B), (C), ...?

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,vertical sep=15mm},
    height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small]
    \nextgroupplot[title=(A)]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=(B)]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=(C)] 
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=(D)] 
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `groupplots` library keeps the value of the current plot in the `\pgfplots@group@current@plot` count. So you can create the titles automatically using the `alphalph` package and the following style:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    auto title/.style={
        title=(\AlphAlph{\pgfplots@group@current@plot})
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Then you just add `auto title` to the `axis` options (or to the `\nextgroupplot` options), and you'll get the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    auto title/.style={
        title=(\AlphAlph{\pgfplots@group@current@plot})
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,vertical sep=15mm},
    height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small, auto title]
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is still something I'm not quite solving properly, though this gives the desired result.  As I would have wanted it to work, you would use `\startaddplot` for your first plot and `\nextaddplot` for subsequent plots.

But what happened is that the counter I used is somehow lagging in its step.  So the crass fix I had to apply was initializing the counter to -1 instead of the expected value of 0, and also require you to issue a `\noaddplot` when you are done, to retroactively step the counter for the final plot.

I'm sure someone like egreg will chime in to tell me why my counter isn't keeping up.

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\newcounter{plotno}
\newcommand\startaddplot{%
  \global\setcounter{plotno}{-1}%
  \nextaddplot%
}
\newcommand\nextaddplot{
  \global\stepcounter{plotno}%
  \nextgroupplot[title=(\Alph{plotno})]%
  \addplot%
}
\def\noaddplot{\global\stepcounter{plotno}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,vertical sep=15mm},
    height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small]
    \startaddplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextaddplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextaddplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \nextaddplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \noaddplot
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]